# Shouldn't kramdown rouge generate syntax highlight classes with jekyll?

Tags: javascript, markdown, syntax-highlighting, jekyll

I expected kramdown with rouge to add spans for colorful highlighting, but it just generates a code block.

```
<pre>
<code class="language-py">
def say_hello():
    print "Hello world"

say_hello()
</code></pre>
```

Should I use highlight js to add pretty colors? Shouldn't rouge add the right spans?

My config.yml says:

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
     input: GFM
     syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

Jekyll runs fine, grunt runs fine, I tried:
`gem install kramdown rouge` just to be sure.
I use backticks for code and run jekyll locally.

````
```py
def say_hello():
    print "Hello world"

say_hello()
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With kramdown, use

```
~~~language
... code ...
~~~
```

do get hightlighting (cf the [documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#code-blocks)).

Comment: I wonder why. There is `input: GFM`. It means that Github syntax should work.